# Getting Error as str.charCodeAt is not a function

Tags: node.js

While using Msg91 package from npm, am getting error as str.charCodeAt is not a function at isUnicodeString

this is mycode

```
 module.exports = function(router, msg91){
         router.get('/try', function(req, res){
            res.render('secured/try', {user : req.user});
          });

         router.post('/try', function(req, res){
            var message = 'Hapserve testing message from Developer';
            var mobileNo = parseInt(req.body.phone_no);
            console.log(mobileNo);
            msg91.send(mobileNo, message, function(err, response){
              if(err)
                throw err;
              console.log(response);
             });
          });

      };
```

Help me to sort out this problem..

Comment: Tried debugging that library? See why it fails, what it expects. If you are having difficulty understanding what fails there, show us the function there it fails on, and the input parameters it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the Msg91 npm package, I created a pull request for the author to merge it

Here is the pull request with the error in line 27 in `index.js`

https://github.com/hirenrojasara/Msg91/pull/2

Stay tuned for merging

Comment: tell me what i need to change in index.js

Comment: Go to line 27 and change:
`message = validateMessage(validateMessage);` to `message = validateMessage(message);`

Comment: But my suggestion is to save the index file as a module in your project and not using it through npm, as your update will be override each time you will reinstall the node modules or deploy it to your server

Comment: i have a done a change, but still am getting the same error

Comment: did you restarted your server after changing the file?